# Android AsyncTask and HTTP post - Works only one time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have an AsyncTask in my application that creates a HttpURLConnection.  Next, it calls getOutputStream(), writes some bytes, flushes and closes.  Then it calls getResponseCode(), and getInputStream().  If I need to post code, I can, but thought I'd keep the question small.

When I run this the first time, I get a 200 response code, and I get the correct input stream.

When I run this a second to fifth time, I get a new thread (viewable in the DDMS view), and I receive a 500 response code, and an IOException when getting the input stream.

When I call this a sixth time or more, no new threads are created, and I still get the 500 response code and the IOException.

What can I look for here?  It always works one time and never again.  Has anyone else seen this?  I'm completely stumped.

Here's MINIMAL code (I removed try/catch, variable declarations, app specific stuff, etc):

```
   protected String doInBackground(String... params)
   {
     connectURL = new URL(sWebPath);
     conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

     conn.setDoInput(true);
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.setUseCaches(false);
     conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);

     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

     conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyAppAgent");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

     // Setup my post as a string s.

     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(s.length()));

     conn.connect();
     DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
     dataStream.writeBytes(s);

     dataStream.flush();
     dataStream.close();
     dataStream = null;

     // 200 1st time only, 500 after that.
     responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

     // Works 1st time only, IO error after that
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
     byte[] data = new byte[16384];
     int len = dis.read(data, 0, 16384);

     dis.close();
     conn.disconnect();

     response = new String(data, 0, len);

     // do whatever with my response
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result)
  {
     super.onPostExecute(result);

     // Now I call a Toast message on the original context used to 
     // create this AsyncTask.
  } 

  // The onClickListener of a button calls this AsyncTask (TierRequest class) with only two lines
  TierRequest t = new TierRequest(WhateverMyCurrentActivityIs.this);
  t.execute(A_Constant_Indicating_The_Type_Of_Post);
```

Comment: Complete minimal code, please.

Comment: Try not calling close() on the stream each time. Not sure what ramifications that has so I won't provide that as the answer, but that's what worked for me in the past when I had trouble communicating with a server multiple times.

Comment: I posted minimal code.  I removed try/catch blocks, variable declarations, and application specific processing like what to do with the response, etc.  Other than this, if you do not see something here that should be, then I'm missing it!

Comment: Can you post the code for the part where you are calling the execute() method of the AsyncTask ? How are you calling it multiple times ?

Comment: What URI are you hitting?  Do you get the same error when using a different URI, like http://www.google.com ?

Comment: advantej - The code to call the AsyncTask is very simple.  I posted it above.

Thane - It's an internal server that returns data back.  I am not sure where else I could post a SOAP message to.  What google address could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really feels like a problem on the server (code 500 is almost universally used to indicate some sort of problem in the server side code, although it could be a problem with the web server itself).

Do you control the server code?  Are you possibly opening a file and not closing it, so that additional calls may run into "access denied" or "file already open" errors?

Comment: Another co worker controls the server side.  He's able to post my exact message with XMLSpy (extracted from the Eclipse debugger).  I will confirm with him that he can post multiple times in a row.  That should eliminate the server side in this.

Comment: I posted the same soap message with XMLSpy twice, and it failed the second time.  This confirms it's not my code.  We'll have to investigate the server.  Thanks for all the responses.  I should have thought to try that.